# Google App Engine : can't create project with location set to EU?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

**PROBLEM**

When I create a new Node.js project on the Google App Engine dashboard, eu location is greyed out.

I also see a small message: "Some locations aren't available because they don’t support Node.js yet.".

---

**QUESTION:**

Have you faced a similar issue ?

Are my users from eu going to face significant lag ?

Is there really no way I could find to deploy my website in an EU location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js runs on their Flexible environment (Beta) that uses standard Docker containers. At the moment it's only for US based projects. [GAE Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs)

There is a significant delay if you're also fetching data from a database in the US from EU.

I suggest you wait for the EU option or run your own container.